# Why is my Sitemap.CurrentNode null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Making the Sitemap.CurrentNode work in my code is oddly a problem.

I haven't figured out how to list code on STOF yet... so here is the code that will easily be displayed.

> **Title:** "localhost/home.aspx/about"
>       Response.write(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title)
>
> **Title:** localhost/Web.sitemap "
>       siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0"
>       siteMapNode url="localhost" title="ROOT"  description="parent "
>       siteMapNode url="localhost/Home.aspx/about" title="About"  description="mommy I'm cold ">
>       /siteMapNode
>       /sitemap

**MVC routing is used.** 
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = ""})

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every ASP.NET control works with ASP.NET MVC. You can check out this project to make it work: http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you.. I see that for full features I need to use the MVC sitemap module. thank you.